# HorizontalPager with ScrollableTabRow when page list is changed - How to keep the previous user tab selection

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I use https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/ with tabs.

Is there any mechanism to keep the current user page selection in case a page is removed from initial list of pages?

Also, in case the current user selected page is removed, the new selected page should be reset to 0 index.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code not as images please